# define row level security poliicy for supabase superadmins

Tags: supabase, row-level-security

Trying to create a policy in supabase to allow super admins to make new organisations. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**: the organisations_members table has the columns user_id and role. I want to equal `role = 'superadmin'` in the last line, whereas I (think I) want to return `user.id` to match with `auth.uid()`.

```
create policy "Superadmins can do all operations on orgs" on organisations
    for all using (
        auth.uid() in (
            select user_id
            from organisations_members
            where role = 'superadmin'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```sql
create policy "Superadmins can do all operations on orgs" on organisations
    for all using (
        auth.uid() in (
            select o.user_id
            from organisations_members as o
            where o.role = 'superadmin'
        )
    )
```